# Post to Drupal using facebook account through Rest Server

Tags: android, facebook, rest, drupal, oauth

I have a Drupal 7 with Services 3 module install.
I enabled Rest Server and was able to login and post content using Rest calls.
Now I want to allow Facebook users to login and post content through the **REST** interface.
How is that possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You mean, from facebook to your site? You will need to build a facebook app which will call the REST API and get those content published on your site!

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to a Facebook OAuth Service for Drupal, go ahead and check out https://drupal.org/sandbox/utneon/1903856. It's experimental, but I looked over the code before and it's at least a good starting point.

I am not sure of your exact implementation, but this allows an iPhone/Android app to login using oauth into your site using services. One they are logged in, they can post content using any other service.